# Applying a function on a groupby table that depends on the value of another column and returns all other columns intact

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df` and its rows are basically logs of record temperatures `T` from a given station `ID` at a given time `date` (each day, each station has one record high and one record low). The column `MinMax` tells me if it's a record high or a record low. It looks like this:

```
df
      Date      ID        MinMax       T
0  01-01-2020   UH24GT2    MAX       13.4
1  02-01-2020   UJ24GT1    MIN      -23.5  
2  02-06-2020   UK21GT4    MAX       38.5
3  15-07-2020   JK32HT6    MAX       43.1
```

I would like to group these temperatures by date, and for each date, extract the maximal record high temperature and minimal record low one and their associated stations where the observation has been done. An expected result would be something of the likes of:

```
df_min_max
      date       ID MIN     T MIN     ID MAX   T MAX
0  01-01-2020   HT21GT2     -28.4    JK21HT2    43.4
1  02-01-2020   UI24GT3     -31.2    UJ23HJ5    40.8
2  03-01-2020   JK21HT4     -30.3    JH12TH4    38.5
3  04-01-2020   BE12HT6     -29.8    JK34UT5    43.1
```

(Note that I don't care that much if there are several stations ID which have a same record high or record low. Having the ID of just one of these stations is good enough)

I have tried doing this by creating a custom function `min_or_max` that is applied on the grouped dataframe (by date) and iterates over the groups of "sub"-dataframes constructed from a second groupby on `MinMax` to know if it should use min or max. This also returns the index of the passed by dataframe so that I can go back into it and look for the ID of the maximal or minimal entry.

```
def min_or_max(dS):
    for name, group in dS.groupby(['MinMax']):
        if(name == 'TMAX'):
            maxT = group['T'].max()
            IDmax = group['T'].idxmax()
        else:
            minT = group['T'].min()
            IDmin = group['T'].idxmin()
    return pd.Series({'ID max':IDmax, 'maxT':maxT, 'ID min':IDmin, 'minT':minT})

df_min_max = df[['Date','MinMax','T','ID']].groupby(['Date']).apply(lambda x: min_or_max(x))
df_min_max['ID max'] = df['ID'].iloc[df_min_max['ID max'].values].values
df_min_max['ID min'] = df['ID'].iloc[df_min_max['ID min'].values].values
```

Truth is, this works. But it is quite long. And, even though I've just started to use Python a month ago, I somehow feel like this is just a very weird way to do it... So I was wondering if there is a faster/clever way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first filter rows by `MAX` rows and use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `max` and [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html), it working because `ID` is converted to index, similar for `min` and `idxmin`, last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
m = df['MinMax'].eq('MAX')
df1 = (df[m].set_index('ID')
            .groupby('Date')['T']
            .agg([('ID MAX', 'idxmax'),('T MAX','max')]))
df2 = (df[~m].set_index('ID')
             .groupby('Date')['T']
             .agg([('ID MIN', 'idxmin'),('T MIN','min')]))

df_min_max = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index()
```

If need working with multiple columns with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = (df[m].drop('MinMax', axis=1)
            .sort_values(['Date', 'T'], ascending=[True, False])
            .drop_duplicates('Date')
            .set_index('Date')
            .add_suffix(' MAX'))
df2 = (df[~m].drop('MinMax', axis=1)
             .sort_values(['Date', 'T'])
             .drop_duplicates('Date')
             .set_index('Date')
             .add_suffix(' MIN'))

df_min_max = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: What if I have multiple columns in addition to ID that I would like to keep., Is this also feasible? (To put all these columns in index, do the groupby and aggregate and then reset_index)

Comment: @mwoua - It working, but in `ID MIN, ID MAX` got tuples like `('UH24GT2', 'val')`. so added another solution.

Comment: Alright. I guess it should be `('ID MAX', 'idxmax'),('T MAX','max')` instead of `('ID MAX', 'max'),('T MAX','idxmax')` but otherwise, this does exactly what I expect it to do when I have only 4 columns. I will test your second suggestion later for multiple columns. Thanks!